# Groupby Method returning incorrect counts Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I can count the values of each possible value for the sentiment column, and then I can group the same data by the brand and the sentiment, but the values are obviously incorrect, since they don't add up with the total values for each sentiment.

```
brand_sentiment_train.sentiment.value_counts()

pivot_df = (brand_sentiment_train.groupby(['brand', 'sentiment']).size()
                                 .unstack(fill_value=0)
            )
pivot_df
```

I'm not smart enough to figure out what the issue is that is causing the groupby method to incorrectly group the sentiments with the brand, so I am hoping someone else can see what the error is. All I know is that it seems to be an issue with the groupby method.

I tried to group the data by sentiment and brand, and I was expecting to have the total amount of each sentiment add up to the same amount of each sentiment that I determined for the sentiment feature individually, but instead, the values are way off, and it appears that when I try to group by both sentiment and brand that somehow the sentiment is not being counted correctly.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the dataset (while I agree it can be tricky for you to provide an example that triggers the issue if you don't know what is the issue, you can nevertheless provide a small example explaining that you don't manage to reproduce the error with your real dataset).

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have NaNs in `brand` that have a non-NAN value in `sentiment`.

[`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on `sentiment` will count the row with NaNs in `brand`, but [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) will drop the NaNs.

Assuming this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'brand': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', pd.NA, pd.NA],
                   'sentiment': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', pd.NA, 'c', pd.NA, 'c', pd.NA]})

  brand sentiment
0     A         a
1     A         a
2     A         b
3     B         b
4     B         c
5     B      <NA>   # ignored by value_counts and groupby
6     C         c
7     C      <NA>   # ignored by value_counts and groupby
8  <NA>         c   # counted by value_counts, ignored by groupby
9  <NA>      <NA>   # ignored by value_counts and groupby
```

Let's compare:

```
df['sentiment'].value_counts()

sentiment
c    3
a    2
b    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

And:

```
df_pivot = df.groupby(['brand', 'sentiment']).size().unstack(fill_value=0) 
df_pivot.sum()

sentiment
a    2
b    2
c    2        # now we have 2, the row with NaN was ignored
dtype: int64
```

You can ask `groupby` to keep the NaNs with `dropna=False`:

```
(df.groupby(['brand', 'sentiment'], dropna=False).size()
   .unstack(fill_value=0).sum()
)

sentiment
a      2
b      2
c      3
NaN    3
dtype: int64
```

Likewise:

```
df['sentiment'].value_counts(dropna=False)

sentiment
c       3
<NA>    3
a       2
b       2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```